# Can angular page be invoked from an email link?

Tags: angular, browser, client-server

I have spent hours to figure out how to invoke Angular page from an email link without any success.

I have a client (Angular) - server (c#) application (and the IIS web server between them).

I am using IIS as my web server.

I am implementing user registration functionality.
Upon request from the client (providing me with an email and password) I am calling my c# back end controller that sends an email (with the link to my angular client) back to the client.
The client can click on the link and that would bring him back to my angular app where I can confirm that the client is registered.

Anyway that is the idea.
The problem I am having is that when the client clicks on the link the browser opens and displays 404 error `The requested resource [/account/verify-email] is not available`.

The link in an email looks like this:

http://localhost:8080/account/verify-email?token=70880C6098208A2F300FC249E081D3471FC614FE203D8E5575D781F91A7B8F342F62AFE080A130A9

I have the route `account` defined in main routing module `AppRoutingModule`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'account', loadChildren: accountModule },
    { path: 'profile', loadChildren: profileModule, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'admin', loadChildren: adminModule, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: { roles: [Role.Admin] } },
    { path: 'schedule', loadChildren: scheduleModule },
    { path: 'report', component: RaportForDateComponent },
    { path: 'floating', component: FloatingSchedulesComponent },
    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
```

... and the second route `verify-email` defined in the `AccountRoutingModule`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: LayoutComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
            { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
            { path: 'verify-email', component: VerifyEmailComponent },
            { path: 'forgot-password', component: ForgotPasswordComponent },
            { path: 'reset-password', component: ResetPasswordComponent }
        ]
    }
];
```

My web.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Force Index.html" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/scheduler"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What else do I need to do (or configure) for the link to open successfully in the browser? Is there any documentation on that topic anywhere?

Comment: Have you deployed your Angular app on IIS too? If you run it on default 4200 port with dev-server it will not work.

Comment: I have deployed it on IIS for port 8080. It generally works - just registration does not.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55105748/2050306

Comment: I have provided my app with the web.config in src folder. I updated angular.json for item src/web.config. I am still getting the same error. What am I doing wrong? I have updated my post for web.config that I have.

Comment: It works after I have changed  url from `http://localhost:8080/account/verify-email?` to `http://localhost:8080/scheduler/account/verify-email?`.  I don't understand why? But it worked. Can I somehow configure it to not use `scheduler` word in my URL?